# Why doesn't html body print <p> element after loading a function?

Tags: html

I am studying some basic HTML and testing out some code snippets. I am looking at how to write to the document by using `document.write` but the overall html code isn't outputting what I was expecting.

This is the code that I ran:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>write example</title>

  <script>
    function newContent() {
      document.open();
      document.write("<h1>Out with the old - in with the new!</h1>");
      document.close();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="newContent();">
  <p>Some original document content.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the output i expected to get:

```
Out with the old - in with the new!
Some original document content.
```

This is what I actually got in my console:

```
Out with the old - in with the new!
```

Could some please explain why? Thank you!

Comment: `document.write` will create a new document rather than append to the current document. Perhaps look at other DOM manipulation methods such as `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to keep the existing HTML content whilst using `document.write` you need to obtain a reference to it prior to calling the `write` method. You can do this by `cloning` the existing body content.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>write example</title>
      <script>
        function newContent() {
            var content=document.body.cloneNode(true);

            document.open();
            document.write("<h1>Out with the old - in with the new!</h1>");
            document.write( content.innerHTML );
            document.close();
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="newContent();">
        <p>Some original document content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can use another method to manipulate the existing DOM which is probably more preferable in many cases. I mentioned `insertAdjacentHTML` so this alternative example does just that:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>write example</title>
      <script>
        function appendNewContent(){
            document.querySelector('p:last-of-type').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<h1>Out with the old - in with the new!</h1>')
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="appendNewContent();">
        <p>Some original document content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You might use `document.write` to build a new HTML file dynamically - for instance in some sort of popup window. It's use on the web is not as common as the other DOM manipulation methods